SQL: How to select lines when column B equals to certain value and column A is in a certain range
for example , this is a table I have .
If B=1 , then A should between 0 and 10 ,so customer1 is selected , customer4 is not selected.
If B=2 , then A should between 11 and 20 ,so customer3 is selected , customer6 is not selected.
If B=3 , then A should between 21 and 30 ,so customer2 is selected , customer5 is not selected.
Final result is customer 1,2,3 are selected.

I tried to write 3 subqueries and join them together, didn't get the result I want.
I end up getting the customer who meet three conditions , actually I need to get customer who meet any of three conditions.

"I tried to write 3 subqueries and join them together, didn't get the result I want" - Show us that query you wrote.

Also, please don’t use images as no one can copy their contents. Use editable text, appropriately formatted

It sounds like a case expression would be doable if you don't have to many ranges to consider.

I think you can do this with some simple arithmetic:
SELECT * FROM myTable where a between (b*10)-9 AND (b*10);

Eg when b is 2 the row will be selected if a is between 11 and 20 inclusive.

With integer division: a / 10 = b - 1 or b = floor(a /10) + 1 if not using integer math. Not sure which of these options seems cleaner to me.

@shawnt00 the 2nd one is the better optiono of the two as it allows for index use on column b

@JoelCoehoorn yeah, I should have been thinking about sargability myself. Of course the first one is also b = a / 10 + 1 with the integer divide. I was thinking more about math aesthetic at the time.
